# Python - How to mask a class from being executed in unittest on runtime

Tags: python, python-unittest, django-unittest

Please see the code below. I was trying to implement a test suite for my project

```
import unittest
class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1_first(self):
        print("First test case")

    def test_2_second(self):
        print("Second test case")

class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_3_third(self):
        print("Third test case")

    def test_4_fourth(self):
        print("Fourth test case")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # val = 1        <-- getting from user
    # if val == 1:
    #    Execute test cases in TestClass2
    # else
    #    Execute test cases in TestClass1\
    unittest.main()
```

I will get the class name as *command line argument* and I need to run each class of test according to the argument. Means I need to select and run some classes of test cases on runtime. **So can any one help me to prevent a class from unit test execution at runtime**? The problem is It's not allowed to use the method like passing class name while execution

Comment: Can you give an example of how exactly you want it to work?

Comment: @Cyphall, done. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is already [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface). You can run specific class via command:

```
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass1
```

If you really need to do it in your scpript, you can pass your classes to `unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName` and then run test suite with `unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)`. It will look something like this:

```
test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName('__main__.TestClass1')
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test_suite)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`unittest.main()` already parses `sys.argv` to allow the running of specific classes or individual tests.

For example, if your script is named `test.py`, you can run the following to run just `TestClass1`:

```
python test.py __main__.TestClass1
```

Or the following to run just `TestClass1.test_1_first`:

```
python test.py __main__.TestClass1.test_1_first
```

If you wish to do it in your script, you can pass the name of test you want to run as the `defaultTest` argument:

```
unittest.main(defaultTest='__main__.TestClass1')
```